# Understand Command Pattern in Swing

Tags: java, swing, design-patterns

I can see how Swing uses Decorator and Observer pattern.

Observer: Every component(eg. `JButton`) is a subject which can add `observers(ActionListeners)`. When someone pushes a button it notifies all its `ActionListeners` by calling their `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`.

But how about Command Pattern?

When I am making classes that implements `ActionListener` (eg: `MyActionListener`) the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` is now the execute command?

It confuses me that `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` is used both as a `execute()` and a `update()` method. Am I right here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here is an article that will help.](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/design-patterns-the-command-pattern--cms-22942) Basically, it is saying you can create concrete command classes that interact with a target object by deriving the ActionListener.  Then you can expand what an action event invoker will do by registering these decoupled commands to it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, so basically making an object that encapsulates the behavior and other information that is needed when an action takes place can be seen as using the [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

The Wikipedia article linked above uses the [`Action`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html) interface as an example of the command pattern in Swing. The `Action` interface is a subinterface of [`ActionListener`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html), so a class that implements `Action` will have to implement the `actionPerformed` method.

Therefore, a class implementing `Action` will be encapsulating some operations which will be performed when an action occurs. And that class itself can be seen to follow the command pattern.

When it comes to the implementation, in general, an [`AbstractAction`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractAction.html) can be easier to use than implementing `Action` as it has several methods that needs to be overridden. An example using `AbstractAction` can be:

```
class MySpecialAction extends AbstractAction {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Perform operations.
    }
}
```

The `MySpecialAction` is a command pattern object -- it has the behavior it must exhibit when an action takes place. When instantiating the above class, one could try the following:

```
MySpecialAction action = new MySpecialAction("Special Action", mySpecialIcon);
```

Then, the action can be registered to multiple components, such as `JButton`s, `JMenuItem`s and such. In each case, the same `MySpecialAction` object will be called:

```
JMenuItem specialMenuItem = new JMenuItem(action);

/* ... */

JButton b = new JButton(action);
```

In both cases, the action that is associated with each component, the button and the menu item, refer to the same `MySpecialAction` action object, or command. As we can see, the `MySpecialAction` object is functioning as a object following the command pattern, as it encapsulates some action to be performed at a the time when an action takes place.

Comment: Thank you very much. I get it :)
But let’s say I wanted to be able to undo. If i make a interface UndoableAction that extends the interface Action with undo() method. Then JButton b = new JButton(new MyUndoableAction()); would still not have undo functionality.

Comment: Ehm by that I mean, Swing can't possible know that there is a undo method. actionPerfomed() gets called automaticly when a button is pressed.

Comment: @bobjink: Yes, the JButton is expecting an Action rather than an MyUndoableAction, so it doesn't know how to "undo", and it will never call the undo() method. The objects to which the MyUndoableAction is handed off to needs to know how to implement the undo. I can't point to a good resource, but I suspect there are quite a few how-to's for implementing an undo. (continued...)

Comment: @bobjink: The text component features page has a way to implement an undo/redo for text components. Maybe that can be a hint as to a way to implement a undo/redo. --> http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#undo

Comment: @bobjink: If you created an abstract class that had undo-able functionailty (and implements the ActionListener) and registers itself to some kind of undo-able list when an action is performed, then derive your concrete commands from this abstract class...it wouldn't be too hard to get undo-able commands.  If that doesn't make sense, post a question about undo-able commands and you might get more detail.

Comment: But where is Invoker and Reciever in Swing command pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting take on it and you might be right, but I see it as something that's performed, period.  The reason for the action being performed can be a state change, or a mouse click, but it's still a Command in the Command Pattern sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on it :

http://blue-walrus.com/2011/10/swing-and-design-patterns-%E2%80%93-part-3-command-pattern/

The key is that your action is an interchangebale unit. You can have this action behind many buttons or menus. Eg. a Save action can hang behind the 'save' menu option, and also hang behind the 'save' icon.